# How to fix local path from json in React.js?

Tags: json, reactjs

How do i fix a local path from Json to my React components rendering,

I searched for answer all over the internet, but NO luck :(

```
NOT WORKING :(
[
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "id": "001",
        "price": "$995",
        "imgUrl": "./Pictures/219.jpg"
    }
]

WORKING, BUT TURTLE SPEED :/
[
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "id": "001",
        "price": "$995",
        "imgUrl": "http://www.placekitten.com/200/200"
    }
]
```

import React from 'react'
class Product extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={this.props.imgUrl}> />
            <p>Name: {this.props.name}</p>
            <p>Id: {this.props.id}</p>
            <p>Price: {this.props.price}</p>
        </div >
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure if you're using Webpack to serve your Images. I'm going with the assumption that you're not and here's basic way to serve images from you're `public` directory.

here's structure:

```
public
|-assets
    |-pictures
       |-219.jpg
|-src
    |-myImgs.json
    |-App.js
```

json file:

```
  {
        "name": "Apple",
        "id": "001",
        "price": "$995",
        "imgUrl": "./pictures/219.jpg"
  }
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import myImgs from './myImgs.json'

class App extends React.Component {
...
render() {
  return(
   <>
     <img src={myImgs.imgUrl} alt={myImgs.name} />
   </>
  )
 };
...
};
```

Comment: I am using webpack to host the server. But i want to put all my image in a folder Images. Then i want the path in json file to link to the image folder.

Comment: I also have a component Search with the following to render every single data I store in json file:                                                                                                                                   const product = this.state.Data.filter(search(this.state.search)).map(data =>
            <Product
                name={data.name}
                id={data.id}
                price={data.price}
                imgUrl={data.imgUrl}
            />)

Comment: That should still work, but webpack won't be serving the images if you have them in your `public` dir.